# IBM Bluemix Discovery - query parameter

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I have created a Discovery service on my bluemix account. I want to query my documents from a nodejs application.

I have built a query with some aggregation, tested it using the bluemix online tool and it's working well.

Now when I query the collection from my code, whatever my parameters are, I always receive all of my documents with the enriched text and so on. I think I am missing how to send the query attributes to the service (like filters and aggregations).

Here is my code:

```
var queryParams = {
  query:'CHLOE RICHARDS',
  return:'title',
  count:1,
  aggregations:'nested(enriched_text.entities).filter(enriched_text.entities.type:Person).term(enriched_text.entities.text, count:5)'
};

discovery.query({environment_id:that.environment_id, collection_id:that.collection_id, query_options:queryParams }, function(error, data) {
  if(error){
    console.error(error);
    reject(error);
  }
  else{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    resolve(data.matching_results);
  }
});
```

And the result is always:

```
{
  "matching_results": 28,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "fe5e2a38e6cccfbd97dbdd0c33c9c8fd",
      "score": 1,
      "extracted_metadata": {
        "publicationdate": "2016-01-05",
        "sha1": "28434b0a7e2a94dd62cabe9b5a82e98766584dd412",
        "author": "Richardson, Heather S",
        "filename": "whatever.docx",
        "file_type": "word",
        "title": "no title"
      },
      "text": "......
```

Independantly of the value of the `query_option`parameter. Can you help me?

**EDIT**

Instead of the `query_options:queryParams`, I have used  `query:"text:CHLOE RICHARDS"` and it's working well. Now my problem still remains to find the right parameter format to add the aggregations I want

**EDIT 2**

So I have looked at [IBM's example on Github](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/discovery-nodejs) more carefully, and the parameters are now formatted like this:

```
const queryParams = {
  count: 5,
  return: 'title,enrichedTitle.text',
  query: '"CHLOE RICHARDS"',
  aggregations: [ 'nested(enriched_text.entities).filter(enriched_text.entities.type:Person).term(enriched_text.entities.text, count:5)' ],
  environment_id: '1111111111',
  collection_id: '11111111111'
};
```

It works well if I use only the query attribute. Now if I only use the `aggregations` one, all the documents are sent back as a result (which is understandable) but I have no aggregation part, so I can not access the list of proper name in my documents.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not look right. I you are going to use `query` then you will need to construct a query search like `text:"CHLOE RICHARDS"`

If you want to perform a natural language query then you should be setting the parameter `natural_language_query`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. It looks like it. I have used `text:"CHLOE RICHARDS"` with the same result. If anything, this request should send back only one document, not 28.

Comment: Also, in the [watson discovey API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?node#query-collection), there is no `text` among the query option, just `query`...

Comment: I think I am starting to understand what you meant, see the edit of my question....how would you complete the query parameter to add an aggregation to it?

Comment: Best to take a look at the documentation - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/query-reference.html#aggregations

Comment: Hello, I already did, and the aggregation part is well formatted (I tested it using the discovery web interface and it gave me exactly the result I wanted). My problem is to format the parameter of the query in my code.